# Modifying shape colour based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Am looking to modify the shape colour based on a linked cell value ...

The shape is 'test' and the cell value "X11". I'm getting the error that the object does not support this property or method ...

```
Sub CChange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

   With ws.Shapes.Range(Array("test"))
        If .Range("X11") = 1 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(18, 38, 43)
        ElseIf .Range("X11") = 2 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this , your with statement is wrong.
You are not working with worksheet hence you cannot access range with .Range.

```
Sub CChange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

   With ws.Shapes.Range(Array("test"))
        If ws.Range("X11") = 1 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(18, 38, 43)
        ElseIf ws.Range("X11") = 2 Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```